# Why is document.getElementById('tableId').innerHTML not working in IE8?

Tags: javascript, dom, internet-explorer-8

I modify `document.getElementById('').innerHTML` with Java Script in a page. It's working fine in Firefox, but not IE8. Please see below for more details:

HTML Code:

```
<table>
  <tr id="abc">
     <td id="ccc" style="color:red;">ccc</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Java Script code:

```
  document.getElementById('abc').innerHTML = '<td id="bbc" style="color:yellow;">abc</td>'
```

When I run the JS code in Firefox, it will change the display word from 'ccc' to 'abc', but it's just not working in IE8, does anyone know why? Is there any way I can make this work in IE8 as well?

Comment: FWIW, this kind of issue is exactly why I use jQuery -- or some other library -- for working with the DOM

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Since the problem is in IE8, [see MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533897.aspx):

> The property is read/write for all objects except the following, for which it is read-only:  COL,  COLGROUP,  FRAMESET,  HEAD,  HTML,  STYLE,  TABLE,  TBODY,  TFOOT,  THEAD,  TITLE,  **TR**.

(emphasis mine)

[Colin's work-around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344470/document-getelementbyid-innerhtml-not-working-in-ie8/1344475#1344475) (setting `innerText` on the `td` instead of `innerHTML` on the `tr`) is a good one in your case. If your needs become more complex, you'll have to resort to [The Table Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532998.aspx#TOM_Methods).

Comment: if I want to change the whole td element what should I do? for exp:

HTLM code
<table>
  <tr id="abc">
     <td id="ccc" style="color:red;">ccc</td>
  </tr>
</table>


JScode:
document.getElementById('abc').innerHTML = '<td id="abc" style="color:yellow;">abc</td>'

Comment: **@jin yong** `var tds = document.getElementById('abc').getElementsByTagName('td'); for(var i=0;i<tds.length;i++) { tds[i].style.color = 'yellow'; }`

Comment: Just an addition. This isn't limited to IE8 - all versions of IE suffer from this innerHTML bug.  http://tinyurl.com/ltar5f

Answer (score 5):

Since TR's innerHTML is read-only as a few people have said, you are better off changing your markup to target the TD:

```
<table><tr><td id="changeme"> ... </td></tr></table>
```

Then you can set the content of the TD as you wish via innerHTML, and change other properties by setting them on the DOM node:

```
var td = document.getElementById("changeme");
td.innerHTML = "New Content";
td.cssText = "color: red";
td.className = "highlighted";
```

You get the idea...

This saves you the overhead of destroying and creating an extra DOM element (the TD)

Answer (score 3):

On another StackOverflow question I found a link to a blog post written by the guy who implemented that part of the Trident engine. It is a design flaw (due to lack of time and backward compatibility issues) that was never fixed. You can [read his notes (including his personal workaround) here](http://www.ericvasilik.com/2006/07/code-karma.html).

However, to fix it on my project, since I was already using jQuery, I just used jQuery's `.html()` function.

```
// OLD 
localRows[cIndex].innerHTML = '<div>Test Div</div>';

// FIXED
$(localRows[cIndex]).html('<div>Test Div</div>');
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe IE behaves strangely when you play with the innerHTML of `tr` elements. I would select the row with `getElementById`, and then select the td and alter that one's innerHTML:

```
document.getElementById('abc').firstChild.innerHTML = 'abc';
```

(Though you have to be careful with this: often the whitespace between the tr and the td will be considered a valid node)

There's a whole heap of special functions for working with tables in the DOM

```
var tblBody = document.getElementById(tblId).tBodies[0];
var newRow = tblBody.insertRow(-1);
var newCell0 = newRow.insertCell(0);
```

See all the functions here: http://www.mredkj.com/tutorials/tablebasics1.html

Answer (score 2):

innerHTML is readonly for  as pointed out here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533897%28VS.85%29.aspx

The property is read/write for all objects except the following, for which it is read-only:  COL,  COLGROUP,  FRAMESET,  HEAD,  HTML,  STYLE,  TABLE,  TBODY,  TFOOT,  THEAD,  TITLE,  TR.

Why are you not just putting an idea around the  and changing that particular value?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a `<div></div>`, you can also use `<span></span>`

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead:

```
document.getElementById('abc').innerText = 'ccc';
```

Comment: If you are going to use innerText you have to workaround the fact that Firefox doesn't (yet?) support it http://www.google.com.au/search?hl=en&client=firefox-a&rlz=1R1GGGL_en___AU314&hs=8ts&q=innerText+Firefox&btnG=Search&meta=

Comment: @MatthewLock Firefox doesn't support the `innerText` as it's a non-standard property, Firefox supports the standard `textContent` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks its very helpful `.html()`

I was using

```
document.getElementById('site'+cValue).innerHTML=tableReadyElem; //work with mozila not ie

$(document.getElementById('site'+cValue)).html(tableReadyElem);//work for both
```