# Recaptcha is not showed by IE8 in ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-8, recaptcha

I'm using Recaptcha ASP.NET control and it works fine on all browsers except IE8. When I'm opening a page with recaptcha it simply is not displayed on page. IE says that there's an error on the page. Here are the details:

```
Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Timestamp: Wed, 2 Oct 2013 11:53:48 UTC


Message: Unknown runtime error
Line: 112
Char: 424
Code: 0
URI: https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/js/recaptcha.js
```

Maybe someone knows the remedy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Simple workaround:**
Google's recaptcha js has an issue with nested tables in IE, make sure

```
<recaptcha:RecaptchaControl
ID="recaptcha"
runat="server"
PublicKey="your_public_key"
PrivateKey="your_private_key"
/>
```

is **NOT** nested in a table.

**Additional Info:**
I came across the same issue when adding a recaptcha to a contact form. In `$.widget.innerHTML='<div id="recaptcha_area">'+d+"</div>"`
d contains tables and tr and in IE it is unhappy with writing Tables and or TR via innerHTML. [More info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344470/why-is-document-getelementbyidtableid-innerhtml-not-working-in-ie8). It does not have the same issue as long as recaptcha code is not in a table. You can move the div around via css if placement is an issue