# Unknown Runtime Error when using JavaScript to append CSS to Body in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I'm having an issue inserting a CSS @import rule into my `<body>` in Internet Explorer 8. I'm doing this as a way to defer non-critical CSS.

When I run the following code I get an "Unknown Runtime Error" on line 6 (`ref_obj.innerHTML = ...`):

```
var css_path_str = "my.css",
el_body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
ref_obj = document.createElement("style");

ref_obj.type = "text/css";
ref_obj.innerHTML = "@import url(\""+css_path_1_str+"\");";

el_body.appendChild(ref_obj);
```

As you can probably guess, the code works on Chrome and Firefox without any issue.

After doing a search here on SO, I stumbled on this post - [Why is document.getElementById('tableId').innerHTML not working in IE8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344470/why-is-document-getelementbyidtableid-innerhtml-not-working-in-ie8) - where it says that `innerHTML` for `STYLE` [and a few other elements] on IE is read-only.

Any ideas how I can edit my code to work around these limitations?

**NOTE**: Only pure Vanilla JavaScript.

**EDIT**:

Problem solved, but just for completeness, here is the code that should work (cross-browser).

```
var css_path_str = "my.css",
el_body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
ref_obj = document.createElement("style");
ref_obj.type = "text/css";

el_body.appendChild(ref_obj);

if(ref_obj.styleSheet)
{
    //IE
    ref_obj.styleSheet.cssText = "@import url(\""+css_path_str+"\");";
}
else
{
    //Other Browsers
    var ref_obj_text_node_obj = document.createTextNode("@import url(\""+css_path_str+"\");");
    ref_obj.appendChild(ref_obj_text_node_obj);
}
```

Comment: You can set the content of `<style>` elements with `innerText` I think; there's some IE-only property like that.

Comment: did you try using a `link` (*`href` attribute for link*) instead of a `style` ? (add it to the `head`)

Comment: There's no `innerHTML` attribute of a `<style>` tag. You can create a textNode and append to it.

Comment: @marekful ... except `innerHTML` does work in other browsers.

Comment: @Pointy Just tried `innerText` and it doesn't work

Comment: @ObinwanneHill right; I know that there's some way to do that in IE because I've done it. Give me a sec and I'll find the old code.

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli I'm looking to use this in `<body>` and I think I read some place that `<link>` shouldn't be in body [I'm sure it'll work but want to do something cross-browser].

Comment: A `<link>` tag won't work; the goal here is to put CSS source into an element, and that doesn't make any sense for a `<link>` tag.

Comment: @Pointy i suggested a `link` because the only thing inserted is an `@import` rule pointing to a url (*so an external link*).

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli ah OK, I see what you mean. Yes that might work (though we're talking about IE8 here so who knows).

Comment: good point. (*the reason i kept it a comment*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do to make IE happy is use the `styleSheet.cssText` property of the node after you've inserted it into the DOM:

```
var css_path_str = "my.css",
el_body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
ref_obj = document.createElement("style");
ref_obj.type = "text/css";

el_body.appendChild(ref_obj);
ref_obj.styleSheet.cssText = "@import url(\""+css_path_str+"\");";
```

Comment: Hmmm...it's saying "styleSheet is null or not an object".

Comment: Also, if I don't remove `ref_obj.type = "text/css";`, IE crashes. What a weird browser.

Comment: @ObinwanneHill that's odd, but the `type` attribute isn't needed anyway; browsers always interpret `<style>` elements as CSS.  I know that the `.styleSheet.cssText` thing works. Maybe you have to add the element to the DOM first? (In my code, the `<style>` element is already in the DOM. I don't know why that would matter, but it's IE.)

Comment: You are quite right. Apparently, I have to append the `<style>` element to the DOM before I use `.styleSheet.cssText`. Did that and it works. I can't see the @import in the DOM inspector, but I have a rule in the CSS file that modifies a div on the page and that is the only way I know that it's working. Will edit your answer and accept.

Comment: Edited your answer inline with my original snippet. I hope you don't mind?